# UITableView - get list of UITableViewCells in an indexPath.section

Tags: iphone, uitableview

Is there a way I can iterate over a list of UITableViewCells contained in an indexPath.section?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to get a cell at a specific index. But this will only return a cell if it is currently visible in the table.

What are you really trying to do? Why do you need all cells in a section?

Comment: Does it really only return a cell if it is visible? Or is it only called if the cell is visible?

Answer (score 0):

It's long ago that this question was asked but this might help other people searching for a solution.

```
NSInteger mySectionIdentifier = 0;
NSArray *visibleCells = self.tableView.visibleCells;
NSMutableArray *sectionCells = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:visibleCells.count];

for (UITableViewCell *cell in visibleCells) {
    NSIndexPath *cellIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (cellIndexPath.section == mySectionIdentifier) {
        [sectionCells addObject:cell];
    }
}
```

As you see this only works for visible cells but it would be easy to change the code to retrieve all cells instead of the visible ones.